# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException "X is not a valid port. Valid ports are: Y

Tags: java, maven, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I am trying to use my WSDL SOAP Service:

```
public void batchReg(String[][] records){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/EndUserService/?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (url == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
    QName qname = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplService");
    Service service = Service.create(url,qname);
    EndUserService obj = service.getPort(qname,EndUserService.class);
    obj.register(records);
    System.out.println("Complete!");
}
```

Yet when I run this, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://EndUserService/}EndUserServiceImplService is not a valid port. Valid ports are: {http://EndUserService/}EndUserServiceImplPort
```

So then I changed the QName declaration to:

```
QName qname = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplPort");
```

But then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://EndUserService/}EndUserServiceImplPort is not a valid service. Valid services are: {http://EndUserService/}EndUserServiceImplService
```

Which is what I had previously.

**WSDL Exerpt**

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://EndUserService/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://EndUserService/" name="EndUserServiceImplService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/EndUserService/?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://EndUserService/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/EndUserService/?xsd=2"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add a specific port QName

```
public void batchReg(String[][] records){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/EndUserService/?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (url == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
    QName qname = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplService");
    System.out.println(url);
    Service service = Service.create(url,qname);
    
    QName qport = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplPort");
    EndUserService obj = service.getPort( qport,EndUserService.class );
    obj.register(records);
    System.out.println("Complete!");
```